# Program type already present: android.support.v7.util.MessageThreadUtil$1$1

Tags: java, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-debug

After adding Appodeal sdk my project I keep getting this compilation error:

> Program type already present:
>   android.support.v7.util.MessageThreadUtil$1$1 Message{kind=ERROR,
>   text=Program type already present:
>   android.support.v7.util.MessageThreadUtil$1$1, sources=[Unknown source
>   file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

**Module app gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nkdroid.videochat"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs-aar'
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0"

    implementation 'com.github.Triggertrap:SeekArc:v1.1'

    implementation name: 'adcolony-sdk-3.2.1', ext: 'aar'
    implementation name: 'mmedia-6.4.0', ext: 'aar'
    implementation name: 'mobvista_alphab', ext: 'aar'
    implementation name: 'mobvista_appwall', ext: 'aar'
    implementation name: 'mobvista_appwallext', ext: 'aar'
    implementation name: 'mobvista_common', ext: 'aar'
    implementation name: 'mobvista_interstitial', ext: 'aar'
    implementation name: 'mobvista_mvdownloads', ext: 'aar'
    implementation name: 'mobvista_mvjscommon', ext: 'aar'
    implementation name: 'mobvista_mvnative', ext: 'aar'
    implementation name: 'mobvista_nativeex', ext: 'aar'
    implementation name: 'mobvista_offerwall', ext: 'aar'
    implementation name: 'mobvista_playercommon', ext: 'aar'
    implementation name: 'mobvista_reward', ext: 'aar'
    implementation name: 'mobvista_videocommon', ext: 'aar'
    implementation name: 'mobvista_videofeeds', ext: 'aar'

}
```

can anybody help me to solve the error!

Answer (score 2):

Try removing **android-support-v7-recyclerview-23.1.1.jar** from app/libs/ dir and rebuild. It conflicts with **com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0** in your gradle build config.

Comment: how you know there is a jar in lib folder